# PowerPoint: reuse a slide multiple times in a presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I'm afraid I already know the answer to this one, but wanted to be sure:

Is there any option to reuse a slide within a presentation? For example: If I have an overview slide containing the architecture of my application, I'd like to show it after each chapter in my presentation to point out what parts we've just covered.

Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: You can copy and paste the slide itself? Or are you asking how to save it as a 'template' so you can import the template as a slide?

Comment: Neither. I'd like to somehow define a reference to a slide, so I could simply reuse without having to copy paste it

Comment: Ah I see... and this would allow you to change just 1 of the instances and it would update all?

Comment: Yes, indeed :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say you have the following slide structure:

Title -- Agenda -- Topic A -- Topic B -- Topic C

Say the topics consist of several slides each and you want to show the agenda after the last slide of  each topic.

Frankly, the easiest way to do this is to simply copy and paste the agenda slide between the respective slides. As a visual indicator of where you are in the prezzo, you can then also highlight the current agenda item and give the audience an indication of how much longer they will be able to enjoy the presentation.

**Alternative:** You can define a custom slide show that features just the "Agenda" slide. (Slide Show > Custom Slide Show > Custom Shows > New > select Agenda slide).

Then, on the last slide of each topic, create a shape or link, which (either on click or on hover) shows the custom slideshow (Select text or shape > Insert > Action > Mouse Over tab > Hyperlink to > select custom slide show) ... (and then returns to the current slide).

You can copy the shape or link to all other slides where you want to quickly show the agenda. You can put an invisible shape into a corner, for example, and set it to display the agenda custom slide show on hover. Then click or hit enter to return to the calling slide and advance to the next topic.

A custom slide show can either branch to the end of the presentation or back to the calling slide, but it cannot branch to the next slide in the sequence after the calling slide. And this is where the custom show alternative falls short. You'll always need to go back to the calling slide in order to progress to the next slide in the prezzo.

The benefit of the custom show solution is that there is only ***one*** agenda slide, and if you need to change it, you only need to change it in one place and won't have to copy and paste it all over the deck again.

Frankly, I'd prefer the linear way of inserting multiple instances of the agenda slide, especially since you can give your audience an indicator of where in the agenda you are -- by highlighting the current agenda item, -- and since you can just click through the deck, without having to concentrate on clicking or hovering over special shapes or links.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't have too many of these, define a new custom layout in Master view.  Make it look like what you want this slide to look like, then whenever you need the slide in the actual presentation, insert a new slide and assign it this layout.

Simple to set up and very light weight.

Comment: That's actually a pretty neat idea :)

Comment: And you can still put where-are-we indicators on it!

Answer (score 2):

You can reuse slides but this may not be exactly what you're after.

The concept appears to be, create a single slide as a new Power point file and save it. This is now your 'reusable slide'

In the Ribbon click Home. Then click New Slide button to display the menu and select Reuse Slides option located at the very bottom of the list.

A new window appears where you can either Browse or use a Slide Library. I think you'll need to browse.

> Browse Slide Library lets you access slides from a Microsoft Office
>   SharePoint Library. This option will only work if a Slide Library is
>   set up for you -- slide libraries are only set up by large companies.
>   If you work in a large company, ask your system administrator to set
>   this up for you.)

[Source and more details](http://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/interface/reuse-slides-in-powerpoint-2010.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the slide you want to repeat (in this example the Agenda slide) to your clipboard.
2. Add a new slide where you want to put a copy.
3. Within this new slide use Paste Special > Paste Link to paste an image copy of the original.
4. Modify the image to cover the entire area of the slide.

Now, when you modify the original slide, it updates the images on all the slides where it has been copied! If you are working with an agenda, you can also highlight the number you are at.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution might be useful for some people, and does not appear to have been mentioned.

I simply add a button to a slide with a link back to the existing pages that I want to  re-use.